# Oracle: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to create this table:

```
create table departments
(
  departments_id number primary key,
  departments_name varchar2(30), 
  departments_block_number number
);
```

But I got this error:

> create table departments
>                   *
>   ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Comment: Looks like there is allready a table named `departments` in your database.

Comment: @Jens, or it could be a view, or almost any other type of object :)

Comment: View, yes, but not any other types of objects. (Tables and views share the same name space.)

Comment: @jarih Tables, Views, Sequences, Private synonyms, Stand-alone procedures, Stand-alone stored functions, Packages, Materialized views, and User-defined types share a single namespace, so it could certainly be one of quite a few object types. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm

Comment: It could be any stored object.

Comment: Then how would i come out of that..

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you try to create new object with the name that is already used by an other object in the schema.

```
SELECT *
FROM all_objects
WHERE object_name = upper('departments')
and OWNER = upper('your_schema')
```

Now you can see which object is created in the schema with the name `departments`

You can resolve this issue by renaming your table or drop the existing ***object if that is no more in use***.

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason behind this might be you forgot to commit at the end.

I was creating a bunch of tables in an sql file. It looked something like this:

```
DROP TABLE LogPurchaseCostChange CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE LogPurchaseCostChange(
    ...
    ...
);


DROP TABLE LogInventoryAddition CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE LogInventoryAddition(
    addition_date date,
    phone_id number,
    old_quantity number,
    new_quantity number,
    FOREIGN KEY(phone_id) REFERENCES Phone(id)
);
```

`LogInventoryAddition` was my last table and I encountered the mentioned error on this table. I was confused why I was given this error although I dropped the table. Then adding `commit;` after declaring the table solved my issue.

Comment: Same case here, while my liquibase is running on the pipeline